# Variable UILabel name

Tags: swift, variables, uibutton, uilabel

Is it possible to make a label as a variable? I have multiple labels:

```
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at0: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at9: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at12: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at15: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at18: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var FL1at21: UIButton!
```

Sample Function:

```
       else
       {
           UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "RedFl1")
           self.FL1at0.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal); self.ProgressUpdate()
       }
```

Is there a way to set the table in a way to work like this:

```
self.FL1at"\(TimeStamp)".setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)//TimeStamp comes from function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let dict: Dictionary<String, UIButton> = ["FL1at0": FL1at0, "FL1at3": FL1at3, ...]
let x = "FL1at\(TimeStamp)"
if let y = dict[x] as? UIButton {
    y.setTitleColor(UIColor.red, for: .normal)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
But you can save buttons in a dictionary:

```
var dic: [String: UIButton] = ["FL1at0": FL1at0]
```

then you can use name to access it like:

```
dic["FL1at\(TimeStamp)"]?.setTitleColorxxxx..
```